# Firestore API has not been used in project 416788152002 before or it is disabled

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I really don't know what the problem is. But since I want to take data from my Cloud Firestore and want to display it in the app, it doesn't work. I get the error message:

```
W/Firestore( 8928): (24.4.1) [WatchStream]: (aab9534) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project 416187152002 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=416187152002 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., cause=null}.
```

My Body:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:prody/application/auth/todos/observer/index.dart';

class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ObserverBloc, ObserverState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is ObserverInitial) {
          return Container();
        } else if (state is ObserverLoading) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is ObserverFailure) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("Failure"),
          );
        } else if (state is ObserverSuccess) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: state.todo.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final todo = state.todo[index];
            return Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 50
            );
          });
        }
        return Container(
          child: Text("-"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

entities:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:prody/domain/entities/id.dart';
import 'package:prody/domain/entities/todo_color.dart';

class Todo {
  final UniqueId id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final bool done;
  final TodoColor color;

  Todo(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.body,
      required this.done,
      required this.color});

  factory Todo.empty() {
    return Todo(
        id: UniqueId(),
        title: "",
        body: "",
        done: false,
        //color ist 0 also die erste color, bei todo_color.dart
        color: TodoColor(color: TodoColor.predefinedColors[0]));
  }

  Todo copyWith({
    UniqueId? id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    bool? done,
    TodoColor? color,
  }) {
    return Todo(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      body: body ?? this.body,
      done: done ?? this.done,
      color: color ?? this.color,
    );
  }
}
```

todo Repository implementation:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:prody/domain/entities/todo.dart';
import 'package:prody/core/Failures/todo_failures.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:prody/domain/repositries/todo_repository.dart';
import 'package:prody/infastructure/extensions/firebase_helpers.dart';
import 'package:prody/infastructure/models/todo_model.dart';

class todoRespositoryImpl implements todoRespository {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  todoRespositoryImpl({required this.firestore});

  @override
  Stream<Either<TodoFailure, List<Todo>>> watchAll() async* {
    final userDoc = await firestore.userDocument();

    // right side listen on todos
    yield* userDoc.todocollection
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => right<TodoFailure, List<Todo>>(snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => TodoModel.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
            .toList()))

        // error handling (left side)
        .handleError((e) {
      if (e is FirebaseException) {
        if (e.code.contains("permission-denied") ||
            e.code.contains("PERMISIION_DENIED")) {
          return left(InsufficientPermissions());
        } else {
          return left(UnexpectedFailure());
        }
      } else {
        return left(UnexpectedFailure());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<TodoFailure, Unit>> create(Todo todo) {
    // TODO: implement create
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<TodoFailure, Unit>> delete(Todo todo) {
    // TODO: implement delete
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<TodoFailure, Unit>> update(Todo todo) {
    // TODO: implement update
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

[The data I want to query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhF0p.png)

I would like the message to go away and the problem resolved.

Comment: And what happens when you go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=416187152002 and check if the API is enabled?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm redirected to Google Cloud and it says: You don't have permission to view this page - The required permissions are:
Project 416187152002

resourcemanager.projects.get
Check that the project ID is valid and you have permissions to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I used an **outdated** `google-services.json` file. This bug has been keeping me busy 10 hours a day for two days now without finding a solution. I tried all of them, but nothing worked. If you re-paste `google-services.json` it probably still **won't work** because you have to **run** `flutter clean` afterwards and then `flutter pub upgrade`. I hope I could help you

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 possible points of failure in my opinion and those are with solutions:

1. Check whether your firestore database API is enabled for this follow:

   - Goto [firestore](https://firebase.corp.google.com/) and select your project
   - click on Firestore database from the build dropdown situated at the left side
   - If you are able to see your database then consider your API is enabled if not you will see the create database button hit create with your required options then it will be automatically enabled.
2. If you have enabled the API earlier and are still seeing this error check that your service account has the necessary permissions to access the firestore db this can be verified by:

   - Goto [cloud console IAM](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and click on view by roles
   - Check whether Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent has a service account which is something like `firebase-adminsdk-@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and has exact project id as your firebase project id.
3. Check on the [App Engine Settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings?project=_) page to ensure it's not disabled for your project as it's required to run firestore db.

Also consider adding one document manually to the db then try after some time

If all these didn't work consider contacting [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support)

Comment: 1 - im able to see my database, 2 - it has the exact same project id as my firebase project id

Comment: 3 - it is not disabled and i added three documents manually to the db