# Google Cloud asking to enable Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a GCP novice. I'm trying to deploy a Flask API (Python) to GCP's Cloud Run (I watched a bunch of tutorials, and they all use Cloud Run). This Flask API uses data in my Firebase project.

When I deploy it to Cloud Run, and make a request to it, the logs return a 400 response and say the "Cloud Firestore API is disabled" and that's why it's returning this reponse and raising an exception. However, **I don't want to use the Cloud Firestore API. I want to use my existing Firebase project.** Is GCP getting confused about which one to use?

My Flask server imports:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth, firestore, initialize_app
```

Initializing Firebase:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('firebase-key.json')
initialize_app(cred)
```

Comment: A Firebase project **IS** a GCP project.  It just has a different looking console new some unique features.  Otherwise everything under the hood is the same stuff.  Are you saying that you are already using Firestore in the same project (both Firebase and GCP)?  Or are you saying you have two different projects, and you want one project to reach into the other project? The latter is going to be very difficult to configure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a Firebase Firestore database on https://firebase.google.com/ with user data already and everything, and I would like my Flask API hosted on GCP's Cloud Run to access the data there as I have been doing locally.

Comment: I'm asking if they are both in the same project.  If you created a new GCP project separate from your Firebase project, then i wouldn't expect what you're doing to work without a lot of configuration.  If they are in the same project, it should just work.

Comment: Got it. My apologies. Yes, they are 2 different projects.

Comment: Then what you're describing in the question isn't surprising at all and sounds normal. Code running in one project cannot simply reach into another project without configuring the SDK to know about the other project and use it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Doug Stevenson in above comments

> Code running in one project cannot simply reach into another project without configuring the SDK to know about the other project and use it.

You will need to enable the Firestore DB either through CLI or through the Firebase console. So the prompt you are getting is intended as you  must be using any firestore service for that the Firestore DB initialization is required hence the prompt.

You can refer to this document on [Build and deploy a Flask CRUD API with Firestore and Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/building-flask-api-with-cloud-firestore-and-deploying-to-cloud-run) and stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974098/18265638) for more information.